# Discord py button stops working in while loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to create a racing minigame through a discord bot and had problems with the starting phase.

Basically what I want is for someone to run the command /race and let as many people as they want join, afterwards I am trying to end up with a list containing the IDs of all users that are participating in the race (the person that ran the /race command + all people that pressed the "join race" button)

The problem is that I'm trying to update my response everytime someone joins the race to contain a list of all those participating, I managed to do that by editing the response every iteration of the "while (time.time() - start_time..." loop but I don't think I have to mention why that's not a good idea - it's very slow and I'm really just editing the message for no reason.
I thought I could get around this by using an if statement that checks if any new user IDs were added to the self.view.racers list and then and only then update the message with the new updated racers list.

Problem is it from some reason completely ignores the button clicks and the interaction fails. By my testing I kind of realized that (all though I may be wrong) when I was editing the message at every iteration it also updated the message and allowed the button click to register, but when I stopped updating the message the button click never registers (also worth mentioning that I only get the error after the while loop ends which backs up my argument cuz I update the message at the end of the loop) - any way around this? I'm not that experienced with discord.py and couldn't really figure out a solution for this on my own.

Could anyone help me out here? thank you!

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.racers = []

    @discord.ui.button(label="Join Race!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def join_race(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You joined the race!", ephemeral=True)
        self.racers.append(interaction.user.id)


class StartRace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = MyView()

    async def start_race_message(self, interaction):
        self.view.racers.append(interaction.user.id)
        start_time = time.time()
        racers_list_len = len(set(self.view.racers))
        epoch = get_epoch_value()
        embed = create_race_starting_message_embed(list(set(self.view.racers)), epoch)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=self.view)

        while (time.time() - start_time) < TIME_TO_START_RACE:
            if len(set(self.view.racers)) != racers_list_len:
                embed = create_race_starting_message_embed(list(set(self.view.racers)), epoch)
                await interaction.edit_original_response(embed=embed, view=self.view)
                racers_list_len = len(set(self.view.racers))

        embed = create_race_started_message_embed(list(set(self.view.racers)))
        await interaction.edit_original_response(embed=embed)
```

This is what happens when you run the command btw

```
@bot.tree.command(name="race", description="Race your friends!")
async def race(interaction):
    start_race = StartRace()
    await start_race.start_race_message(interaction)
```

imported modules

```
import datetime
import time
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
```

Let me know if I missed any detail and I'll try and update the post asap!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a timeout for your view that is not affected by the use of components, you can use a function that waits for the desired time and then stops the view:

```py
import discord
from datetime import timedelta

TIME_TO_START_RACE = 60


class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.interaction = interaction
        self.racers = [interaction.user]
        self.end_time = discord.utils.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=TIME_TO_START_RACE)

    async def start_race(self):
        # send a message with the view to start the join proccess
        await self.interaction.response.send_message(embed=self.join_race_embed(), view=self)

        # sleep until the end time
        # this will not be affected when the buttons are used
        await discord.utils.sleep_until(self.end_time)
        # stop de view
        self.stop()

    def join_race_embed(self) -> discord.Embed:
        # discord time formating
        show_time = discord.utils.format_dt(self.end_time, "R")
        emb = discord.Embed(description=f"The game will start {show_time}.", colour=0x5aa5fa)

        # show players
        emb.add_field(name="Players", value="\n".join(u.mention for u in self.racers))

        return emb

    @discord.ui.button(label="Join Race!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def join_race(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if interaction.user in self.racers:
            # this will cause "This interaction failed error"
            return
        self.racers.append(interaction.user)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=self.join_race_embed())

    @discord.ui.button(label="Leave Race", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def leave_race(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if interaction.user not in self.racers:
            return
        self.racers.remove(interaction.user)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=self.join_race_embed())
```

Comment: Hey! sorry it took me a bit to respond, I was at work.
I tried changing my code following your suggestions and it did fix a lot of the problems I had, so thank you!

a couple of small issues however,
the reason I had the while loop is because I wanted there to be an X amount of secs time window for users to join (the TIME_TO_START_RACE variable), and only after start the race itself. So having the timeout was not exactly my intention because it resets the counter pretty much after someone joins.

Comment: I was also wondering if there was a way for me to send a message the user a message after they click the join race button (something along the lines of "Entered race successfully!" or something) and if I could somehow add a leave race button in the interaction_check func.

also, is there any way to have functions like start_race or start_race_embed outside of this class? in my head this class should've only took care of the buttons and everything to do with the discord ui view, but if not then that's totally fine it's just a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Again thank you a lot, you're an absolute lifesaver.

Comment: @why i updated the answer two show you a way to perform the timeout withou time reseting.

Comment: I don't see the need to send a message to the user, as they will see that their name has been added to the player list

Comment: I think it's better to develop the entire game within the `discord.ui.View` class. You can create new methods and it becomes easier to interact with the `self` variables. This is your choice

Comment: any way to make the leave button show up only in an ephemeral response the user gets whenever they try to join the race after they already joined it? similar to what "Giveaway Bot" has? (example https://imgur.com/a/ubOPHmK)

Comment: @why Yes, but to do this you need to create another view and send it as a response to the leave button

Comment: how can I remove the user from the self.racers list if the button callback is in a whole different class though? (also I assume that by sending it as a response you just mean doing interaction.response.send_message in the if interaction.user in self.racers statement)

Comment: You can pass the `self.racers` list as a parameter to your new view. You can edit the list in another view, and the changes will take effect in any part of your code where this list exists

Comment: does this happen because it's a list and when using arrays in general you use it through their memory address directly?

Comment: Because `list` is a [mutable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) object.